# Arduino Nano SD Append data from existing File (.csv)

Tags: csv, arduino, append, sd-card, fseek

I saw the function "fseek" to get a position into a File. But it doesn't works, i dont know why. I want to add text in the end of the file (append)and have the historical measurements from differents days.

```
    void init_SD(void) {
     // init sd
      Serial.print("Iniciando SD ...");
      if (!SD.begin(chip_select)) {
        Serial.println("No se pudo inicializar");
        return;
      }
      Serial.println("Inicializacion exitosa");
      
      if (!SD.exists("filename.csv")) // voy a escribir el archivo llamado "ensayo.csv": si existe, lo escribo. Si NO existe, lo crea
      { 
        // uso de archivo--> see below "A"
        myFile = SD.open("filename.csv", FILE_WRITE);
        if (myFile) {
          myFile.fseek(myFile.size()); 
          myFile.println("Titulo Archivo");
          myFile.println("Hora de Medicion,Tiempo [s],Corriente [A]");
          myFile.close();
        } else {
          Serial.println("Error creando el archivo");
        }
      }
    }
```

"A": when i use this, the text doesnt appear in the .csv. Should i use "file.fread" before use fseek?

I used SD.open("filename.csv", O_APPEND) and  SD.open("filename.csv", O_WRITE) but the same problem.

Hw: Arduino nano + shield "datalogger" with RTC and SD card.
Sw: Arduino IDE with (SD.h, SPI.h).

Thanks!

Comment: the SD library's FILE_WRITE flag opens the file for append. so new writes are appended at the end of the existing file. you don't have to use `seek`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Juraj! That doesnt occurs in .csv, at least in my case. Every time the microcontroller is reset (power off), the new content overwrite the old data. IF you have some example working to share, it would be grate.

Comment: do you have a current version of the SD library?

Comment: I think so, do you have a url where its avaiable download arduino last libraries? Please share! 

Thanks again Juraj

Comment: Library Manager in Arduino IDE has the latest version